# which data structure should I use in java to store duplicate values?

Tags: java, data-structures

Which is the best data structure to store duplicate values in java? And how easy is to retrieve values from it!?

thanks
**EDIT #1** I am reading contents from 1000 files, and I want to put each files content as tokens in some data structure. I used Hashtable but i am not able to view many words when I am doing that. thats why I want a data structure which can store the duplicate values.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate values?"  What data is being stored?  What operations do you need to perform on these values?  Without more information, this is unanswerable.

Comment: Do you need duplicate values or duplicate references? In other words, do you have multiple objects containing the same content or do you need multiple references to the same object?

Comment: what are the contents? numbers? how do you want to access those later?

Answer (score 2):

For just storing simple values, you should use an implementation of the [`List<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.

To get data from a `List<E>` you can do the following:

```
list.get(index); // will get data at a given index
// or you can iterate over all of the items in the list
for(E item: list) {
    // use E
}
```

Depending on your use either an [`ArrayList<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) will do what you need.

Another option would be a [`Map<K, V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (it's implementation `HashMap`).  This will allow you to save duplicate values under unique keys.

You can get values out of a `Map<K,V>` in the following ways:

```
map.get(someKey); // will retrieve the value associated with a key
// or you can iterate through all of the entries in a map like so:
for(Entry<K,V> entry: map.entrySet()){
    // use entry
}
```

**Response to your edit:**

You may want to use a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the key is the name of the file, and the value is a list of the words in the file.

Your code may look like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for(File f: files) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String();
    data.put(f.getName(), words);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        words.add(s.next());
    }
}
```

At the end of this snipit, `data` will be filled with lists of words from each file.

Comment: well i need to check the value in a data structure, so how can I do that!? Actually i am using hashtable and I think it is skipping some values, despite the fact that I am using unique key.

Comment: @mad What exactly does - "well i need to check the value in a data structure" mean?

Comment: @mad, do you mean that you need to see if the value is in the structure?

Comment: sorry, for my poor knowledge, but I edited my problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

theres lack of info to properly answer this qn.. but anyway, hashmaps could do the trick. retrieval of values can be done in constant time on average..

Comment: Duplicate values in a HashMap? Only if they had unique keys, which seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Or with the key as the value, the value as the duplicate counter.

Comment: its possible to generate unique keys. but, apparently mad_programmer is using a hashtable and its not working for him even with unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `List<E>` but you should implement a `int[] getDuplicateValuesIndexes(String value)` method and a `int getCount(String value)`. These will be useful because in `List<E>` implementations, there are nothing to treat duplicate values as they store just values of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Any java.util.Collection that does not implement the Set interface.  Probably you'll want something that implements a List.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays, to get value use index (I know its incomplete answer, but so is the question)